# App not displaying var string on label

Tags: ios, swift, string, label

I'm trying to make an app that takes a students name and total points (grade out of 1000) and displays it on a label when a button is pressed. The formula of the display is "x student got y grade." For some reason (i'm unsure) i've connected the story board and the code seems right; the label doesn't display the string. Instead it's giving me something like:

"`Optional(UITextField: 0x7ff6696095550;` frame ="etc, etc.

If someone could look at my code and assist me in what i can do to get that string to display on the label - I'd really appreciate it.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var gradeTF: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameGR: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var label1 : UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }



    @IBAction func submitTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        var gradeMS = ""

        if (gradeTF.text?.isEmpty)! {

            gradeMS = "Please enter point total"

        }
        else {
            let grade : Int = Int(gradeTF.text!)!


            if grade > 1000 {
                gradeMS = "ERROR - Invalid point total"
                label1.text = gradeMS
            }
            else if grade > 900 && grade <= 1000 {
                gradeMS = "\(nameGR)'s grade is \"A\""
                label1.text = gradeMS
            }
            else if grade > 800 && grade <= 900 {
                gradeMS = "\(nameGR)'s grade is \"B\""
                label1.text = gradeMS
            }
            else if grade > 700 && grade <= 800 {
                gradeMS = "\(nameGR)'s grade is \"C\""
                label1.text = gradeMS
            }
            else if grade > 600 && grade <= 700 {
                gradeMS = "\(nameGR)'s grade is \"D\""
                label1.text = gradeMS
            }
            else {
                gradeMS = "\(nameGR)'s grade is \"F\""
                label1.text = gradeMS
            }
            }


        func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: This is because you are inserting the `UITextField` object in `gradeMS` instead of the `string` contained in it.

Comment: it's being displayed in the label. can you suggest to me the code or edits i need to make so that my code display correctly? i'm new to swift and self taught; so i'm not 100% sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Adeel, what would the code look like to remedy this; if you dont mind?

Comment: have a look at my answer below.

Comment: did you try the edited answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the text inside your `nameGR` textField instead of the textField itself.

**Replace**

```
gradeMS = "\(nameGR)'s grade is \"A\""
```

**With**

```
gradeMS = "\(nameGR.text!)'s grade is \"A\""
```

everywhere in your `submitTapped IBAction`.

```
@IBAction func submitTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var gradeMS = ""
    let name = nameGR.text

    if (gradeTF.text?.isEmpty)! {

        gradeMS = "Please enter point total"

    }
    else {
        let grade : Int = Int(gradeTF.text!)!


        if grade > 1000 {
            gradeMS = "ERROR - Invalid point total"
            label1.text = gradeMS
        }
        else if grade > 900 && grade <= 1000 {
            gradeMS = name! + "'s grade is \"A\""
            label1.text = gradeMS
        }
        else if grade > 800 && grade <= 900 {
            gradeMS = name! + "'s grade is \"B\""
            label1.text = gradeMS
        }
        else if grade > 700 && grade <= 800 {
            gradeMS = name! + "'s grade is \"C\""
            label1.text = gradeMS
        }
        else if grade > 600 && grade <= 700 {
            gradeMS = name! + "'s grade is \"D\""
            label1.text = gradeMS
        }
        else {
            gradeMS = name! + "'s grade is \"F\""
            label1.text = gradeMS
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any clue why is say's "optional" in the string on the label now?

Comment: sorry I don't understand.

Comment: when i click the button, the string that displays on the label is this:

Optional("danny")'s grade is "F"

danny was the name i used in the name field, and the grade was a 0, so it is an F. i'm wondering why optional is there and why danny is in parenthesis.

Comment: I see. Put and exclamation mark `!` after the `text` property of the `textField` like this `(nameGR.text!)`. I have edited the my answer please check.

Comment: This crashes if `name` is `nil`

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the `UITextField` named `nameGR`:

```
gradeMS = "\(nameGR)..."
```

but you probably want to print it's unwraped text:

```
guard let name = nameGR.text! else {
    print("Uups. We might want to handle empty textfield here")
}

gradeMS = "\(name)'s grade is \"C\""
```

---

Complete method:

```
 @IBAction func submitTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var gradeMS = ""

    if (gradeTF.text?.isEmpty)! {

        gradeMS = "Please enter point total"

    }
    else {
        let grade : Int = Int(gradeTF.text!)!

        guard let name = nameGR.text! else {
            print("Uups. We might want to handle empty textfield here")
            return
        }

        if grade > 1000 {
            gradeMS = "ERROR - Invalid point total"
            label1.text = gradeMS
        }
        else if grade > 900 && grade <= 1000 {
            gradeMS = "\(name)'s grade is \"A\""
            label1.text = gradeMS
        }
        else if grade > 800 && grade <= 900 {
            gradeMS = "\(name)'s grade is \"B\""
            label1.text = gradeMS
        }
        else if grade > 700 && grade <= 800 {
            gradeMS = "\(name)'s grade is \"C\""
            label1.text = gradeMS
        }
        else if grade > 600 && grade <= 700 {
            gradeMS = "\(name)'s grade is \"D\""
            label1.text = gradeMS
        }
        else {
            gradeMS = "\(name)'s grade is \"F\""
            label1.text = gradeMS
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! seems to be working; but now i have it says "optional("Danny")'s grade is "A""

Comment: I was not aware that UILabel.text is an optional. Sorry. I updated the answer.